# weird artifacts when doing Boolean operation

Tags: modifiers, normals, artifacts

[image: Screenshot of object with many Boolean operators]

As shown at picture above I have some problems when doing Boolean operation. The cube bound box is where the operation is happening but somehow Boolean is affecting totally different parts of mesh and breaking them. For example here there are some shading errors but it acts very randomly, sometimes flipping some normals here and there.
I recalculated normals for all objects including cutter and I think I checked all the meshes looking for some holes or something. My question is what should I do or where to look to try to fix that problem? Could be because of bevels, some settings or for example order in the modifier stack?

Here is additional picture of my modifier stack:

[image: Here is additional picture of my modifier stack]

[image]

Comment: Please share your blend file ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help)).  It will beeasier to figure out issues if we can experiment with it.

Comment: @MartyFouts Sorry, that for sure might help you guys  in finding my problem, i think it should available now :)

Comment: it's not the boolean operation but your bevel. Just hide it and the problems are "gone"

Comment: @Chris Thanks! but shouldn't i have an option to add bevel? i mean it shouldn't behave this way right? It's not a big deal but i would like to have that bevel on the model.

Comment: You could try a remesh modifier and then bevel - but i didn’t try that.

Comment: It behaves that way because the Boolean modifier „destroys“ the clean topology

Comment: Thanks a lot @Chris! I will make an update when i will find other ways to fix that but for now i will stick to your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you are working all out of order.

The typical workflow is,

1. Blockout/Low-Poly: This is where you use random primitives, and boolean to your hearts content just get an idea of how everything will fit together, keep everything loose and easy to adjust, don't worry about quad-topology too much. Try to separate things into logical components (e.g. don't make it to where the trigger is fused topologically to the handle, make it a separate object like it would be in real life, etc.)
2. Medium Poly/ Cleanup: start applying modifiers/booleans, to get real geo to work with, start cleaning things up and getting things at least vaguely uniform. Quads are a little bit more important to keep in mind but not absolutely necessary.
3. Bevel/Subdiv/High Poly: Add in control loops, bevel modifiers and/or subdiv mod to get the shading as clean as possible and the curves super sleek and realistic.

Right now you have your Subdiv modifier set as the first modifier in the stack. This is giving the boolean modifiers way to much geo to try to work around, and then the bevel is trying to cleanly split those edges. There's hardly any room to work.

[image]

What you should be doing is something like:

Low Poly: Separate objects, just getting the idea of how things will fit together. No details.
[image]

Mid Poly: Add some preliminary geo before Boolean to make it easier after we apply it.

[image]

Add/Apply the boolean, and then finalize the Geometry.

[image]

You mainly just want to make sure there aren't any massive random n-gons or tiny slivers of triangles. Just get things looking neat and even

[image]

Then, if you've done your job well enough, you might be able to just add a Bevel mod with the profile set to one (to give yourself automatic control loops) and a subdivisions surface on top of it. If that doesn't work you can just use normal control loops. You might need to tweak things a bit with the topology and fiddle here and there, but it should be nearly done at this point.

[image]

Final Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed instructions! i may not need it right now but it will be really helpful in the future!